# Update database mysql using ttgo tcall esp32 with sim800l

Tags: esp32

I'm trying to update my database (mysql, xampp, php) using TTGO Tcall ESP32 that has built in SIM800L whenever a specific text message is received. already done doing the API for post request and works fine using postman. *it's my first time to program an arduino...

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <Adafruit_FONA.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

#define SIM800L_RX 27
#define SIM800L_TX 26
#define SIM800L_PWRKEY 4
#define SIM800L_RST 5
#define SIM800L_POWER 23
#define SIM800L_NET 0

HardwareSerial *sim800lSerial = &Serial1;
Adafruit_FONA sim800l = Adafruit_FONA(SIM800L_PWRKEY);

uint8_t readline(char *buff, uint8_t maxbuff, uint16_t timeout = 0);

#define LED_BLUE  15

String smsString ="";

const char* ssid = "--------";
const char* password = "-------";

String URL = "http://localhost/file.php";

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(SIM800L_NET, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BLUE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SIM800L_POWER, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BLUE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(SIM800L_POWER, HIGH);

  connectWiFi();      //connect wifi

  sim800lSerial->begin(4800, SERIAL_8N1, SIM800L_TX, SIM800L_RX);
  if (!sim800l.begin(*sim800lSerial)) {
Serial.println(F("Couldn't find GSM SIM800L"));
while (1);
 }
 Serial.println(F("GSM SIM800L is OK"));

 char imei[16] = {0}; 
 uint8_t imeiLen = sim800l.getIMEI(imei);
if (imeiLen > 0) {
Serial.println("SIM card IMEI: "); 
Serial.println(imei);
 }

sim800lSerial->println("AT+CNMI=2,1\r\n");

Serial.println("GSM SIM800L Ready");

 }

long prevMillis = 0;
int interval = 1000;

void loop(){

 while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
connectWiFi();
 }
 while (millis() - prevMillis > interval) {
digitalWrite(LED_BLUE, !digitalRead(LED_BLUE));
prevMillis = millis();
}

char sim800lNotificationBuffer[64];          
char smsBuffer[250];
char* bufPtr = sim800lNotificationBuffer;

if(sim800l.available()){
int slot = 0;
int charCount = 0;

do {
  *bufPtr = sim800l.read();
  Serial.write(*bufPtr);
  delay(1);
} while ((*bufPtr++ != '\n') && (sim800l.available()) && (++charCount < (sizeof(sim800lNotificationBuffer)-1)));

*bufPtr = 0;

  if (1 == sscanf(sim800lNotificationBuffer, "+CMTI: \"SM\",%d", &slot)){

    Serial.print("slot: "); Serial.println(slot);
    uint16_t smslen;
    if(sim800l.readSMS(slot, smsBuffer, 250, &smslen)) {
    smsString = String(smsBuffer);
    Serial.println(smsString);
    }
     //update
    if(smsString == "Normal" || smsString == "Imminent" || smsString == "Critical"){
      updateDatabase(smsString);
    }

    if (sim800l.deleteSMS(slot)) {
      Serial.println("SMS deleted successfully.");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Failed to delete SMS.");
    }
   }
  }
 }

void updateDatabase(String status){
int id =1 ;                         //also my structure in mysql is that this is pk and ai
String location = "(location)";

String postData = "Culvert_no=" + String(id) + "&status=" + status + "&location=" + location;

//send HTTP request
HTTPClient http;
http.begin(URL);
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

int httpCode = http.POST(postData);
String payload = http.getString();

//output debug info
Serial.print("URL : "); Serial.println(URL);
Serial.print("Data : "); Serial.println(postData);
Serial.print("HTTP Code : "); Serial.println(httpCode);
Serial.print("Payload : "); Serial.println(payload);

// Delay before processing the next message
delay(5000);

}

void connectWiFi(){
WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
delay(1000);

WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi");

while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
delay(500);
Serial.print(".");
} 
Serial.print("Connected to: "); Serial.println(ssid);
Serial.print("IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
delay(5000);
}
```

had already plenty of iterations at the updating part.
it does notifies at the serial monitor if a message is received.

I tried testing it by texting the sim that i inserted in the ttgo esp32, it shows at the serial monitor that it puts it in a slot, but the condition where the specific text message (Normal || Imminent || Critical) does not call the post Update.

Comment: So what is the question or the problem? Please edit your post and explain it.

Comment: I tried testing it by texting the sim that i inserted in the ttgo esp32, it shows at the serial monitor that it puts it in a slot, but the condition where the specific text message (Normal || Imminent || Critical) does not call the post Update.

Comment: Learn [String.indexOf()](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/strings/StringIndexOf/) or read the [function definition](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/indexof/).